# Running a entire SQL script via python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking to run the following `test.sql` located in a folder on my `C:` drive. I've been playing with cx_Oracle and just can't get it to work.

`test.sql` contains the following.

```
CREATE TABLE MURRAYLR.test
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE MURRAYLR.test2
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50)
);
```

This is my code:

```
import sys 
import cx_Oracle 
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user,'password,'test.ora') 
cursor = connection.cursor() 
f = open("C:\Users\desktop\Test_table.sql")
full_sql = f.read() 
sql_commands = full_sql.split(';') 
for sql_command in sql_commands: 
  cursor.execute(sql_command)
  cursor.close() 
connection.close()
```

Comment: You mention Oracle and your code looks like Oracle but you tagged this with sql server. Which DBMS are you using???

Comment: I'm using Oracle Developer on a Oracle BD

Comment: what have you tried with cx_oracle? is this helpful: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html  ??

Comment: yep, I can import or export tables via cx_oracle, but not able to run an entire scrip where there is two sets of SQL inside.

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague ... can you specify what error are you having, what result are you getting, and what did you expected? Why the python tags if your question don't mention it, and you didn't share any python code?

Comment: @LeeMurray are you able to run a single statement, separately?

Comment: Please post your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't have an oracle database right now. I noticed an parenthesis missing at the very end of the file. I just added it in the edit. Try running with it. Also not sure if "{" and "}" are accepted in .sql files. Try running without them (almost 100% sure database will accept the file without them).

Comment: not sure if this is relevant, but are the curly braces around the statements necessary?

Comment: @LeeMurray after the file is read your first statement will be `{
CREATE TABLE MURRAYLR.test
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50)
)` and second `CREATE TABLE MURRAYLR.test2
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50)
);
}`  . Maybe you should remove the curly braces

Comment: Sorry guys, you can tell I'm a newbee on this site. The {} were a typo on this site only & not in my SQL file

Comment: @LeeMurray can you show the error message? Also, try 'print full_sql.split(';')` . On my system is shows \n characters in the strings which might be the culprit.

Comment: @LeeMurray let me know if the above is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is relevant only if your test.sql file contains new lines '\n\' characters (like mine which I got from copy-pasting your sql code). You will need to remove them in your code, if they are present. To check, do

```
print full_sql
```

To fix the '\n's,

```
sql_commands = full_sql.replace('\n', '').split(';')[:-1]
```

The above should help.

It removes the '\n's and removes the empty string token at the end when splitting the sql string.

Comment: I though you had nailed it then I added a bit of extra code to the sql & it broke again.

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP table test1';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;

Comment: Can you show the error? I see that with this new string, some statements have whitespace around them, so maybe this will help: `sql_commands = [i.strip() for i in sql_commands]
`

Answer (score 0):

`MURRAYLR.test` is not acceptable table name in any DBMS I've used. The connection object the `cx_oracle.connect` returns should already have a schema selected. To switch to a different schema set the `current_schema` field on the connection object or add `using <Schemaname>;` in your sql file.
Obviously make sure that the schema exists.

Comment: The missing ; at the end is not an issue. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html

Comment: nope my SQL work fine & creates the tables in the MURRAYLR schema. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @LeeMurray See the expanded answer.